# The mapping defines a unique automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $a,b\in R$ with $a$ invertible.

I want to show that the mapping $x\rightarrow ax+b$ defines a unique automorphism of $R[x]$ that is identity in $R$.

$$$$

Let $f(x)=ax+b$ and $p(x)\in R[x]$ a polynomial. Then we have the mapping $T:p(x)\mapsto (p\circ f)(x)$.

I have shown $T$ is a ring homomorphism, i.e., $T(p_1+p_2)=T(p_1)+T(p_2)$ and $T(p_1p_2)=T(p_1)T(p_2)$ and that $T$ is bijective.

So, $T$ is an automorphism.

Now, it is left to show that $T$ is a **unique** automorphism that is identity in $R$. How could we do that? Could you give me some hints?

Answer (score 1):

The map certainly defines an endomorphism $\phi$ of $R[x]$. And $x\mapsto a^{-1}(x-b)$ is also an endomorphism $\psi$ which apparently is the two-sided inverse of the given automorphism.

<del>However, in general $\phi$ is not idempotent. Instead $\phi^n(x)$ will be of the form $a^n x+b_n$, and there is no reason event that $a^n=1$.</del>

Comment: How could we show that this automorphism is unique? Could you give me some hints?